# How to make dynamic height with Angular Material and responsive sidebar?

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I followed [this guide](https://zoaibkhan.com/blog/create-a-responsive-sidebar-menu-with-angular-material/) to create a responsive sidebar menu with Angular Material. Now I'm trying to make the content part of the screen render correctly with dynamic data. The content looks fine when rendering a static page. For example, here's the welcome page:

[image: welcome screen]

However, when I have a list screen with dynamic data, I can't scroll up to see the entire list. The list goes above the content section and overflows below it too.

[image: list]

I can fix this by changing the `.content` class from using `height: calc(100vh - 98px)` to `height: auto`, but then it causes regular screens to look funny because the content part doesn't flow to the bottom.

[image: content-auto]

The screen with the list looks a lot better though and you can scroll to see all its contents.

[image: list-auto]

Is it possible to 1) make it so the height is dynamic and stretches to the bottom while allowing scroll-ability? Also, how do I make the static content render at the top instead of the vertical center?

You can see this issue in action by cloning this repo and running its Angular Material example:

```
git clone -b styles-support https://github.com/manfredsteyer/angular-crud.git
cd demo-material
npm install
npm start
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a minimum height of the content div like this

```
min-height: calc(100vh - 98px);
height:auto;
```

This way and height to auto so it will expand and look proper

Comment: Thanks - this works great! I have a related question - do you know how to align the content nearer to the top instead of vertically centered?

Comment: Figured it out! Changing `align-items: center` to `align-items: flex-start` fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

You can fixed this by adding `min-height: 100%` in your **.content** class

Comment: @MattRaible oh sorry I didn't notice that you want static content to render at the top instead of the vertical center. My mistake. :( BTW With my approach your static content will look the same as in your first picture output, I mean at vertical center.